# MongoDB Keys and casting between types

Tags: mongodb, index-tuning, datatypes

This is more of a theoretical question:

Let's say I have a collection of documents, `my_collection`:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("52c679ac7a23e6225b62c51f"),
    "date": ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52c679b63cdecc6508c54fe5"),
    "date": "2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ca15677a23e6d3354fb7b4"),
    "date": "2014-01-03 19:49:48"
}
```

and I then create an index

```
> db.my_collection.ensureIndex({date: 1})
```

Does Mongo automagically figure out it should be a date and then do a cast to date before it hashes for the index? Or does it treat the field as a string serialisation or something else?

What sort of performance impact would I get (if any) not having all the fields as `Date` BSON objects, or is there minimal to no impact?

**EDIT**: I think I failed to clearly communicate another part of the question, but your answer might have already addressed it. Dates stored as `string` will not be included in results where the query uses a `Date()`/`IsoDate()` and vice versa, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a query that would utilize the "date" index will implicitly contain a criteria for that "date" field (value(s) of certain type(s)), Mongo will decide what index/part of the index to use, making the fact of having multiple types of values in the same field moot (as far as indexing is concerned).

Here's an example:

I've added the following data to my Mongo 2.4.4 test db:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c679ac7a23e6225b62c51f"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c679b63cdecc6508c54fe5"), "date" : "2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca15677a23e6d3354fb7b4"), "date" : "2014-01-03 19:49:48" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("42c679ac7a23e6225b62c51f"), "date" : ISODate("2014-02-06T03:48:30.737Z") }
```

Before index creation, any query on the date field (be it with a ISODate or a string criteria) will search through all the 4 documents, this can be confirmed by using `explain()`:

```
> db.t1.find({date:ISODate("2014-02-06T03:48:30.737Z")}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "server" : "P09104:27017"
}

> db.t1.find({date:"2014-01-03 19:49:48"}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "server" : "P09104:27017"
}
```

Once I create the index via `ensureIndex("date")`, doing either a query of type date:"some string", date:ISODAte(...) or date in some range of ISODate values will only look through the pertinent values (2 for each of these queries):

```
> db.t1.find({date: {$gte: ISODate("2014-01-05T03:48:30.737Z"), $lt: ISODate("2014-02-07T03:48:30.737Z")}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "date" : [
                        [
                                ISODate("2014-01-05T03:48:30.737Z"),
                                ISODate("2014-02-07T03:48:30.737Z")
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "P09104:27017"
}
```

This is made more clear if we add even a 3rd type of value for date (numerical) and create something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c679ac7a23e6225b62c51f"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c679b63cdecc6508c54fe5"), "date" : "2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca15677a23e6d3354fb7b4"), "date" : "2014-01-03 19:49:48" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("42c679ac7a23e6225b62c51f"), "date" : ISODate("2014-02-06T03:48:30.737Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca15677a23e6d2354fb7b4"), "date" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca15677a23e6d2254fb7b4"), "date" : 400 }
```

Doing an $or seach for (let's say) ISODate and numerical values (exact match) and then doing an explain on that search will show that only 2 documents are scanned (out of the 6 indexed), showing that having mixed types of values for a field does not lower the efficiency of the index:

```
> db.t1.find( { $or: [ {date: ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z")}, {date: 100} ] } ).explain();
{
        "clauses" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 1,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                        "nscanned" : 1,
                        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "millis" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "date" : [
                                        [
                                                ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z"),
                                                ISODate("2014-01-06T03:48:30.737Z")
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 1,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                        "nscanned" : 1,
                        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "millis" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "date" : [
                                        [
                                                100,
                                                100
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
        "millis" : 0,
        "server" : "P09104:27017"
}
```

Doing a similar $or search with ranges (for both ISODate and numerical) will show that 4 results are obtained after only scanning 4 documents (the string values to not influence the utilization of the index):

```
> db.t1.find( { $or: [ {date: {$gte: ISODate("2014-01-05T03:48:30.737Z"), $lt: ISODate("2014-02-07T03:48:30.737Z")}}, {date: {$gte: 50, $lt: 500}} ] } ).explain();
{
        "clauses" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
                        "nscanned" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
                        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "millis" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "date" : [
                                        [
                                                ISODate("2014-01-05T03:48:30.737Z"),
                                                ISODate("2014-02-07T03:48:30.737Z")
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
                        "nscanned" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
                        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "millis" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "date" : [
                                        [
                                                50,
                                                500
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "n" : 4,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "millis" : 0,
        "server" : "P09104:27017"
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! As a small follow up question and continuing the datetime theme: Having an epoch integer stored as a string will make things a little bit slower, right? As mongo will index it as utf-8 string, rather than 32-bit integer?

Comment: Well, this is something to test with some large enough quantity of data. But I'm fairly sure than any of those values are optimally hashed such as to not make a difference when using such an index. For example with Apache Solr, indexing a Date as a Date object, String, or integer timestamp yields virtually similar results.